# Creating an iOS Facebook SDK Static Library

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I am trying to understand how and what they mean by building a static library, but I just cant wrap my head around it?

I've checked here [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493640/facebook-ios-sdk-how-to-build-static-library-for-xcode-4-3) and it seems like it is explained well for most people but maybe I'm just an idiot or something.

I see here where I'm supposed to change the .sh to this...

`XCODEBUILD_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin`

and then it says to build in the shell... what is the shell and how do i build in it?
also is `Xcode.app` the name of my xcode project? And if so I don't have any .app files in it...

Could someone please walk me through the steps for this?  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell is, well the shell.  OK, I know.  Under mac, you can access it multiple ways, probably the easiest is the Terminal application (under utilities).  It is a program that gives you command line access to the operating system as a user (that's not a pure description but the best I can do considering you have no idea what it is).

A static library is a library that you can link directly into your application.  Dynamic libraries are loaded at runtime.  That's how the iOS framework libraries are loaded when running on the device.  They are already there, and you will get them loaded when the application runs.

A static library is actually linked into the application as a part of the application... the only approved way to access non-apple libraries.

Xcode.app is the name of the Xcode application.