# Facebook sdk issues

Tags: facebook, ios5

I am working on an iphone app that will eventually post an image on the user's facebook.  I have been following directions at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/.  These directions refer to using the static sdk corrected for arc by running the script that comes with the sdk: ~/facebook-ios-sdk/scripts/build_facebook_ios_sdk_static_lib.sh

When I run this script, the library that gets generated is only .h files and not .m files or any other files that you would expect.  When I use this library (add copy of files to my project), running the project, I see the login screen, and hit ok, (and the thread goes to my viewController and I can hit my round rect button I put there) but my fbDidLogin method is never visited by the thread and when I just get the accessToken by calling the facebook class, it's null.  Has anyone ever seen this issue?  Was I supposed to use the .m files from the original facebook sdk and just substitute in the .h files that the script generates?

[Creating an iOS Facebook SDK Static Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235380/creating-an-ios-facebook-sdk-static-library)

[Facebook iOS SDK - How to build static library for Xcode 4.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493640/facebook-ios-sdk-how-to-build-static-library-for-xcode-4-3)

By the way, I am using xcode 4.2 and Lion.

Answer (score 0):

**[UPDATE]**
I managed to solve this by modifying the m files first and the running the bash script to generate the new static library.

since the ARC version uses the static library it's not directly showing the .m files. I'm having the same problem at you. haven't been able to find a solution other than deleting the facebook app and force my app to use safari for authentication instead.